# c# IF isn't properly working, program is not paying attention in void to IF

Tags: c#

so i have a problem that i can't solve for few days, i have nearly done the program, take a look at it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace U1_15
{
class Student
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public int StudId { get; set; }
    public int Course { get; set; }
    public int MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public bool Freshman { get; set; }
    public Student()
    {
    }
    public Student(string lastname, string firstname, DateTime birthday, int studid, int course, int mobilenumber, bool freshman)
    {
        LastName = lastname;
        FirstName = firstname;
        Birthday = birthday;
        StudId = studid;
        Course = course;
        MobileNumber = mobilenumber;
        Freshman = freshman;
    }
}
class Program
{
    List<Student> ReadFile()
    {
        List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"studentai.txt");
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            string[] values = line.Split(' ');
            string lastname = values[0];
            string firstname = values[1];
            var birthday = DateTime.ParseExact(values[2], "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  
            int studid = int.Parse(values[3]);
            int course = int.Parse(values[4]);
            int mobilenumber = int.Parse(values[5]);
            bool freshman;
            if (values[6] == "Fuksas")
            {
                freshman = true;
            }
            else
                freshman = false;
            Student student = new Student(lastname, firstname, birthday, studid, course, mobilenumber, freshman);
            students.Add(student);
        }
        return students;
    }
    DateTime FindOldestBirthDate(List<Student> students)
    {
        DateTime birthDay = DateTime.Now;
        foreach (Student student in students)
        {
            if (birthDay > student.Birthday)
            {
                birthDay = student.Birthday;
            }
        }
        return birthDay;
    }
    void ShowOldestStudent(List<Student> students, DateTime oldestBirthDay)
    {
        foreach (Student student in students)
        {
            if (oldestBirthDay == student.Birthday)
            {
                var age = DateTime.Today.Year - student.Birthday.Year;
                Console.WriteLine("Vyriausias studentų atsovybės narys: {0} {1} {2}", student.FirstName, student.LastName, age);
            }
        }
    }
    int FindMaxCourse(List<Student> students)
    {
        int[] max = new int[4];
        foreach (Student student in students)
        {
                if (student.Course == 1)
                    max[0]++;
                else if (student.Course == 2)
                    max[1]++;
                else if (student.Course == 3)
                    max[2]++;
                else if (student.Course == 4)
                    max[3]++;
        }
        int maxIndex = max.ToList().IndexOf(max.Max());
        maxIndex++;
        return maxIndex;
    }
    int FindMaxCourseCount(List<Student> students)
    {
        int[] max = new int[4];
        foreach (Student student in students)
        {
            if (student.Course == 1)
                max[0]++;
            else if (student.Course == 2)
                max[1]++;
            else if (student.Course == 3)
                max[2]++;
            else if (student.Course == 4)
                max[3]++;
        }
        int maxValue = max.Max();
        int maxIndex = max.ToList().IndexOf(max.Max());
        maxIndex++;
        return maxValue;
    }
    void ShowBiggestCourse(List<Student> students, int biggestCourse, int biggestCourseCount)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Daugiausiai studentų yra: {0} kurso {1} studentai", biggestCourse, biggestCourseCount);
    }
    void OldOnesToFile(List<Student> students)
    {
        string[] lines = new string[students.Count];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Student student in students)
        {
            if (student.Course > 1)
                lines[i] = String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6}", student.LastName, student.FirstName, student.Birthday, student.StudId, student.Course, student.MobileNumber, student.Freshman);
            i++;
        }
        File.WriteAllLines(@"senbuviai.txt", lines);
    }
    void FreshmansToFile(List<Student> students)
    {
        File.WriteAllLines(@"senbuviai.txt", students.Where(student => student.Freshman == true).Select(student => String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6}", student.LastName, student.FirstName, student.Birthday, student.StudId, student.Course, student.MobileNumber, student.Freshman)));
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        Program p = new Program();
        List<Student> students = p.ReadFile();
        DateTime oldestBirthDay = p.FindOldestBirthDate(students);
        p.ShowOldestStudent(students, oldestBirthDay);
        int biggestCourse = p.FindMaxCourse(students);
        int biggestCourseCount = p.FindMaxCourseCount(students);
        p.ShowBiggestCourse(students, biggestCourse, biggestCourseCount);
        p.OldOnesToFile(students);
        p.FreshmansToFile(students);
    }
}
}
```

Well, sorry for putting all my code here, i just can't find anywhere the problem i have. Take a look at my data file too.
[image: file]

Well, long story short, i scan all the students' data and by the end i need to make 2 VOIDS, one that writes all students data to a file WHOSE course are higher than 1. *1
And the one that writes all students data to a file WHOSE are "Fuksas". *2

*1. Problem number 1 - take a look at a code OldOnesToFile. I say to a code, IF student's course is more than 1, write his data to a file. Okey sounds good, right ? Nooo... Program isn't looking at IF statement, as you can see, in my data file all students' courses are 1. So it shouldn't write anything, but it writes all students to a file. Why ? Because there is on the end written "Fuksas" (it means freshman/first degree in university) and SOMEHOW computer is looking at him. I have tested, i can write student.course > 2; < 6; ==5;...It doesn't meter, if there is written Fuksas, it writtes to a file. So, why my program, even if theres written " if (student.Course > 1) ", isn't paying attention to it at all?

*2. Problem number 2 - take a look at FreshmansToFile. Problem is same as above, it pays attention to "Fuksas", i have written: "IF there's written Fuksas in the end, it writtes all student's data to a file (different from above code). Okay it works as i want, but if i changed like "student.Freshman == true" to "student.Course < 1 ", again, computer doesn't care, problem as above. So do you have any ideas what kind of problem is it ? I have tried creating a new project and copy/paste everything and again - same. So maybe, if it's too hard to solve this, maybe there is another way of writting a code that do what i need (writte student's data to a file if his course is more than 1 and...)? I hope you can help me, because i need that work to be done by tomorrow :(

EDIT: I have tried debbuging, ALL code looks good, works as i want, except those 2, believe me, i can't solve this problem maybe for a 2 days, i have tried nearly anything.

Comment: I think you likely get confused, because your different routines/methods always overwrite the same file ("senbuviai.txt"). It would probably be time well spent to learn and practice using the debugger in Visual Studio to observe how your program works/behaves (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger).

Comment: You need to debug through it, line by line. On every line, before it executes, ask yourself 'what do I expect it to do?'. Then run the line. Did it do what you expect? If no, that is a bug - investigate further to understand **why** it didn't do what you expect.

Comment: Your error is - you are writing your outputs to the same file - `senbuviai.txt` - and by that overwriting your first output - try to use different file names in your methods `OldOnesToFile` and `FreshmansToFile`

Comment: @elgonzo No, only one time is written to "senbuviai.txt". Second void writtes to a different file.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to change that it is different file. Still same.

Comment: Remember, a program does not do what you believe it should do but it does what you instructed it to do in the source code.

Comment: Note that your if/else for `if (values[6] == "Fuksas")` could simply be rewritten as `bool freshman = values[6] == "Fuksas";`

Comment: `OldOnesToFile` works fine in that it writes all students whose course > 1 (and nobody else) to the file. `FreshmansToFile` writes a file which contains all the freshmen. If I change `student.Freshman == true` to `student.Course < 1` it outputs nothing to the freshmen file. The only weird thing is that you're using an array, so you get blank lines where the condition isn't met.

Comment: Tried your code and it works… so something is wrong in your verification of the "problem" - try the following, run your app and look at your outputed file does the LastModifiedDate match with the current time - so basically, does the program really output there where you are checking the results.

Comment: I will reinstall the program, because i have tried what u have said.

Comment: I'd say that's unlikely to help. I think you're either looking at a different file to the one being read, or are indeed outputting to the wrong filename. It seems unlikely that reinstalling Visual Studio or the .NET Framework will resolve your issue.

Comment: I've created an [online fiddle](http://rextester.com/WFCVW67289) of your code so that you can see it working.

Comment: When i was testing and changing Fuksas to whatever else, it hasn't wrote to a file, so output path is good.

Comment: So i think it is something bad with my program.

Comment: FYI - since you are only splitting by `' '` every space in your real data breaks your code - for example if someone is called `Jean-Claude Van Damme` - or the mobile number instead of being `"864839042"` -> `"(864) 83 90 42"`